# Managing workers on AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, celery

I occasionally have really high-CPU intensive tasks. They are launched into a separate `high-intensity` queue, that is consumed by a really large machine (lots of CPUs, lots of RAM). However, this machine only has to run about one hour per day.

I would like automate deployment of this image on AWS, to be triggered by outstanding messages in the `high-intensity` queue, and then safely stopped once it is not busy. Something along the lines of:

- Some agent (presumably my own software running on my monitor server) checks the queue size, determines there are `x > x_threshold` new jobs to be done (e.g. I want to trigger if there are 5 outstanding "big" jobs")
- A specific AWS instance is started, registers itself with the broker (RabbitMQ) and consumes the jobs
- Once the worker has been idle for some `t > t_idle` (say, longer than 10 minutes), the machine is shut down.

Are there any tools that can I use for this, to ease the automation process, or am I going to have to bootstrap everything myself?

Answer (score 5):

You can [public a custom metric](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/publishingMetrics.html) to AWS CloudWatch, then set up an [autoscale trigger](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-trigger.html) and [scaling policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-policy.html) based on your custom metrics. Autoscale can start the instance for you and will kill it based on your policy. You'll have to include the appropriate user data in the [launch configuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html) to bootstrap your host. Just like userdata for any EC2 instance, it could be a bash script or ansible playbook or whatever your config management tool of choice is.

Comment: If using Amazon SQS, there is not even a need for custom metrics.  SQS' queue length is one the Amazon CloudWatch metric.  With RabbitMQ, Custom metric + alarm + autoscaling is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Maybe overkill for your scenario, but as a starting point you may want to check out AWS OpsWorks.

http://aws.amazon.com/opsworks/
http://aws.amazon.com/opsworks/faqs/

if that is indeed a bit higher level than you need, you could use aws cloudformation - perhaps a bit 'closer to the metal' for what you want.

http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/